# Why does supabase function return emty array in the following code

Tags: supabase-database

Why does this query return an empty array even though there is data in the WeChat table and users  and that data in the tables match the query?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_chat_info () 
RETURNS TABLE (
  chatId bigint,
  chatMessage text,
  chatDate timestamptz,
  senderName varchar,
  senderEmail varchar,
  recieverName varchar,
  recieverEmail varchar
) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
    SELECT
      we.id AS chatId,
      we.message AS chatMessage,
      we.created_at AS chatDate,
      us1.name AS senderName,
      us1.email AS senderEmail,
      us2.name AS recieverName,
      us2.email AS recieverEmail
    FROM
      "WeChat" we
      JOIN users us1 ON we.sender = us1.id
      JOIN users us2 ON we.receiver = us2.id;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Why does this query return an empty array even though there is data in the WeChat table and users  and that data in the tables match the query?

Comment: There could be a few reasons why this is happening, it could be that the data in the tables aren't matching anything and its failing. Or you could be calling this from the js library and have row level security (RLS) turned on on one of these tables so you aren't matching the criteria to get data. I think you will need to provide more context and some dummy data from each table to get better help.

Answer (score 0):

I was just working with a similar table and so long as your query is working in the SQL Editor your issue is almost certainly Row Level Security. Be sure to disable it or allow read permission for all tables in your query including those in the join statements.